# Find the least value in between the columns using Spark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, sql-function

**I have a dataframe like below and need to find the least value except zeros and add it in a new column as 'Least'.**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0 | 120.0 | 150.0 |
| 200.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.0 | 20.0 | 100.0 |

*I tried with least() function but I didn't get the expected output.*

*expected output would be like below.*

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Least |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.0 | 120.0 | 150.0 | 100.0 |
| 200.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 200.0 |
| 0.0 | 20.0 | 100.0 | 20.0 |

Comment: What was the reasult with least function? It should work fine in your case

Comment: Hi M_S, I'm getting zeros in the least column, but I want to exclude zeros in the least column.

Comment: ok, i get it, please check my sample solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the least values

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

      val df = List(
        (100.0, 120.0, 150.0),
        (200.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 20.0, 100.0)
      ).toDF("column1", "column2", "column3")
      
      val columns = df.columns.toSeq
      
      
      val leastRow = least(
        columns map col: _*
      ).alias("min")

      df.select($"*", leastRow).show
```

Try to improve the **leastRow** method to ignore the zero values. think about replacing the zero values with the maximum possible float value in your use case, **Double.PositiveInfinity** in general ect..
Do not hesitate to post your work and be sure that you'll get help !
Good luck.

Comment: thanks, shalnarkftw.

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions:

1. You can swap 0 to inf when calculating least to skip zeroes
2. You can use udf which will skip zeroes

Option 1)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq((100.0, 120.0, 150.0), (200.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 20.0, 100.0))
val columns = Seq("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns: _*)

// Calculate the least value, swaping all zeroes to inf
val leastValueExpr = least(
  df.columns.map(colName =>
    when(col(colName) =!= 0.0, col(colName)).otherwise(Double.PositiveInfinity)
  ): _*
)
val resultDF = df.withColumn("Least", leastValueExpr)

resultDF.show()
```

Option 2

```
// Define a UDF to calculate the least value, excluding zero values
val leastNonZero: UserDefinedFunction =
  udf((cols: Seq[Double]) => cols.filter(_ != 0.0).min)

// Apply the UDF to calculate the least value, excluding zero values
val dfWithLeast: DataFrame =
  df.withColumn("Least", leastNonZero(array(df.columns.map(col): _*)))

// Show the result
dfWithLeast.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Least|
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|  100.0|  120.0|  150.0|100.0|
|  200.0|    0.0|    0.0|200.0|
|    0.0|   20.0|  100.0| 20.0|
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```